# Not properly set Data in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i'm trying retrieve data from database and dispay in gridview. for create Header i'm using HeaderTemplet Tag. but in gridview always first column of employee id is blank.

my code is as under of aspx page:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Width="99%" GridLines="Both" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <HeaderTemplate>

                            <tr>


                                <th style="padding: 2.5px; width: 10%;" >eid</th>


                                <th style="padding: 2.5px; width: 55%;" >First Name</th>
                                <th style="padding: 2.5px;" >Last Name</th>

                        </HeaderTemplate>

                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:BoundField DataField="idemp" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="fname" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="lname" />

<asp:TemplateField>

                    <ItemTemplate>

                        <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" Width="99%" GridLines="Both" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="ChildGrid">

                        </asp:GridView>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>

    </div>
</form>
```

code behind:

```
namespace WebApplication2
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page

    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                // Populate the GridView. 
                bindGridview();
            } 

        }

        public void bindGridview()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            string constr = @"server=127.0.0.1;user id=root;pwd=n0711p2010p;database=emp";
            using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constr))
            {
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select idemp,fname,lname from emp", con);
                con.Open();
                MySqlDataReader dtreader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                dt.Load(dtreader);
                if (dt.Rows.Count >0)
                {
                    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                    GridView1.DataBind();
                    con.Close();

                }
            }

        }

        //RowDataBound Event  
        protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            //Checking the RowType of the Row  
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                string constr = @"server=127.0.0.1;user id=root;pwd=n0711p2010p;database=emp";
                using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constr))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    GridView child_gridview = (GridView)e.Row.FindControl("GridView2");
                    String CountryId = (e.Row.RowIndex+1).ToString();
                    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select salary,post from emp where idemp="+CountryId, con);


                    MySqlDataReader dtreader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    dt.Load(dtreader);
                    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        child_gridview.DataSource = dt;
                        child_gridview.DataBind();

                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

and output is as under:[image: Gridview]

first column of gridview is always empty.when using HeaderTemplet tag.
and  i want to achieve like this.[image: i want like this]

[image]

Comment: Curious to know wether my solution was helpful to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the nested GridView to span multiple columns, you have to do that in the RowDataBound of the parent GridView. In there you can set the colspan and remove the last 2 cells.

So if you have a GridView

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Id">
            <ItemTemplate>

                <%# Eval("Id") %>

            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
            <ItemTemplate>

                <%# Eval("Name") %>

            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Saldy">
            <ItemTemplate>

                <asp:GridView ID="NestedGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true">
                </asp:GridView>

            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Address">
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="City">
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

And the RowDataBound event

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //check if the row is a normal datarow
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        //cast the row back to a datarowview
        DataRowView row = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;

        //use findcontrol to locate the nested gridview
        GridView gv = e.Row.FindControl("NestedGrid") as GridView;

        //bind data to the nested grid
        gv.DataSource = source;
        gv.DataBind();

        //set the column span to 3 on the cell that has the nested gridview
        e.Row.Cells[2].ColumnSpan = 3;

        //hide the last 2 cells
        e.Row.Cells[3].Visible = false;
        e.Row.Cells[4].Visible = false;
    }
}
```

The only problem is that the cells of the parent and child do not match in width, so you may need to set a fixed width for those columns.

Comment: But problem in inner gridview's columns width. how to make same width as header's width?

Comment: i put screenshot of result at the end of  my question after apply your logic.

Comment: Set the width of the cells directly with `HeaderStyle-Width` (`<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Saldy" HeaderStyle-Width="100">`) or with a CSS class to make sure they are the same width. Or try not to use nested GridViews.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are retrieving the data just fine but not displaying it properly.

You are mistakenly using  `TemplateField` to define headers.

You can simply do the following:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Width="99%" GridLines="Both" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                <Columns>


                <asp:BoundField DataField="idemp" headertext="Employee ID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="fname" headertext="First Name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="lname" headertext="Last Name" />


        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

As you can see the Header names are defined right in bound column.

Enjoy, and let me know if still having issue

Comment: i want sub header, so i'm using <TemplaetField> and  inside that  <HeaderTemplate> tag. it is not possible to create sub header with the solution suggested by you. @daniDev

Comment: If that is the case, you can rephrase your question, so that your requirements are clear.  
Can you please clarify what you are looking for in a sub Header?
A templated field will only allow you to create a header for one column.